# Цикл for в java

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Друзья, не могу понять причину долго работы цикла.
Значит, создаю цикл.

```
for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    // Вычисляем количество цифр в числе i
    int length = (int)Math.ceil(Math.log10(i));
}
```

Вся программа таким образом работает 10ms и благополучно завершается. 
Такая программа работает 3ms:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    // Создаем массив длиной 10 (количество цифр в Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    int[] digits = new int[10];
}
```

А вот эта программа подвисает надолго:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    int length = (int)Math.ceil(Math.log10(i));
    int[] digits = new int[length];
}
```

Почему? Ведь значение `length` всегда будет меньше или равно 10. Этого и не могу понять. Ведь такая программа работает всего 12ms:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    int length = (int)Math.ceil(Math.log10(i));
    int[] digits = new int[10];
}
```

Comment: Какая версия java используется? У меня на 1.7_40 такая же картина, а на новой 1.8_77 не оптимизируется вообще любой вызов `Math.ceil` (можно даже массив не создавать). Если `Math.ceil` заменить на каст к `int`, то все успешно завершается.

Answer (score 2):

В первых двух примерах вычисленное значение нигде не используется, поэтому оптимизатор просто удаляет весь цикл, как будто его нет.

А вот тот пример, где вычисленное значение используется для создания массива, работает по-настоящему. То есть с той скоростью, с какой вычислительные мощности способны.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            int length = (int)Math.ceil(Math.log10(i));
            int[] digits = new int[20];
            digits[0] = length;
        }` 13ms

Comment: Посчитаем частоту процессора в Герцах. 1/(0.013/2**31)=165191049846.15 - 165 ГГц. Отличный проц.

Comment: Возможно я чего-то не понимаю.. http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/160403/5m9RDws842.jpg

Comment: Был бы благодарен, если бы Вы указали, что я делаю не так

Comment: Замерьте, пожалуйста, время работы цикла. for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
            int length = (int)Math.ceil(Math.log10(i));
            int[] digits = new int[length];
        }

Comment: 1ms http://www.picshare.ru/uploads/160403/NG4nJV3Fwx.jpg

Comment: То есть полный цикл в Integer.MAX_VALUE итераций отработает примерно за 36 минут. Для этой программы Java - не лучший выбор. Попробуйте Си.

Comment: На Си получится порядка 7-8 минут. Это если хватит памяти для процесса.